# Was the Huddle problem just a "bug" in the implementation of true two-factor authentication?

Tags: multi-factor, authorization

I've just read the BBC News item [Huddle's 'highly secure' work tool exposed KPMG and BBC files](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-41969061). According to the article:

> **How did this happen?**
>
> During the Huddle sign-in process, the customer's device requests an authorisation code.
>
> According to Huddle, if two people arrived on the same login server within 20 milliseconds of one another, they would both be issued the same authorisation code.
>
> This authorisation code is carried over to the next step, in which a security token is issued, letting the customer access their Huddle.
> Since both User A and User B present the same authorisation code, whoever is fastest to request the security token is logged in as User A.

**Question:** Is this authorization code part of a two-factor authorization (one example of which would be a code sent by SMS to a cell phone)? If so, was this just a poor implmenentation, or was it in fact not really true two-factor to begin with, considering that whomever receives the code first (reguardless of other identity factors) is granted access?

Comment: Whatever they were using to generate the codes was clearly not generating codes fast enough. This looks like an oversight or some sort of incompetency.

Comment: The two options are not mutually exclusive.